# How to start an activity by click of image button of a List view?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

i have a list there is a image `button` in each item when i click on a image i have to start another `Activity` with `intent`

following are my code

my problem is i couldn't call `startActivity()` from custom adapter! !

in custom adapter's `getView()`

```
  holder.profilePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
       { 
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
               Log.d("OnImageButton","Clicked");
               Intent zoom=new Intent(AllProfile.getAppContext(), ImageZoom.class);
               int imageID=holder.profilePicture.getId();
               zoom.putExtra("ImageId", imageID);
               startActivity(zoom)  ; //This line raises error !      
                           }


       });
```

Comment: Use `Activity Context` with it, like  `mContext.startActivity(zoom);`.

Comment: Actually startActivity() is method of Context class. And you have written it on Adapter class's getView's Imageview's Click method so your IDE unable to find it.

Comment: am getting an error like " FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK requires" ! what should i do now ?

Comment: `zoom.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` put before start activity method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass your context to your custom adapter when you create it:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter (Context ctx) {
        mContext = ctx;
    }

    ...
}
```

And in getView use that context to start the Activity:

```
 holder.profilePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
   { 
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
           Log.d("OnImageButton","Clicked");
           Intent zoom=new Intent(mContext, ImageZoom.class);
           int imageID=holder.profilePicture.getId();
           zoom.putExtra("ImageId", imageID);
           mContext.startActivity(zoom)  ; //This line raises error !      
                       }


   });
```

When you create the Adapter in your Activity you should pass "this" as a parameter:

```
 mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
```

Comment: am getting an error like " FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK requires" ! what should i do now ?

Comment: I forgot something. When you create the intent, use mContext instead of AllProfile.getAppContext(). I'll edit the post to add it. Tell me if the error still happens.

Comment: mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this); where do i have to instantiate this ? in my onCreate()?

Comment: Depends on how you designed your Activity, but you can do it in onCreate, yes.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
MainActivity.this.startActivity(zoom);
```